# After forgetting widget adding gives "already exists'

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want add/remove tabs in ttk::notebook at run-time. So, I've made this:

```
ttk::notebook .nb

proc add_tab {} {
  set tab_cnt [.nb index end]
  .nb add [frame .nb.fr$tab_cnt]
}

proc del_tab {} {
  set tab_no [expr [.nb index end] - 1]
  .nb forget .nb.fr$tab_no
}
```

Removing is fulfilled, but adding new tab after removing produces message

```
window name "fr0" already exists in parent
```

How must I correctly remove tab and frame (or other widget, if it is added to tab)?

Comment: you have to [`destroy`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/destroy.htm) it

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

When you `forget` the widget from its parent container, the widget still exists and the name is still in use; it just doesn't show up on the screen, it isn't *mapped*. To free the name up so you can use that again, you need to `destroy` the widget.

That is, instead of:

```
.nb forget .nb.fr$tab_no
```

do this:

```
destroy .nb.fr$tab_no
```

(Destroying a widget makes its container forget it too; that's handled automatically for you by Tk.)